# Drag and drop and then move

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a couple draggable items in a list and 4 possible containers.  This works all fine.  But if an item is dropped into a container that the users didn't want and tries to move it it doesn't move, cant get rid of a "misdropped" item.

Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/8kEKA/2/

Users drags Phoenix onto Team 3 and then realizes it should have been in team to I am stuck trucking to move this.  I tried to add "draggable" to team 3 but that didn't work.

I am still learning the query ui so all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect the sortables to each other. `connectWith`. http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

Comment: Thanks Jack.  I knew it had to be something simple!